# Should I omit the file extension when import types from a d.ts file?

Tags: typescript, eslint

This is a question about the best practice. When importing types from a `d.ts` file, which one below is the most readable and recommended way?

1. `import type { TestType } from 'type.d.ts`. This means never omit the file extension. And once I have declared that it is a `d.ts` file, I have to use `import type` at the same time or ts will throw an error saying that a declaration file cannot be imported without 'import type'.
2. `import { TestType } from 'type.d'`. This means I omit the `.ts` file extension but keep the `.d` to declare that what I import is a type instead of a value from a delcaration file.
3. `import type { TestType } from 'type'`. This means I omit all file extension and just keep the filename itself. To make it work, I have to install the eslint-import-resolver-typescript. Becuase eslint-plugin-import doesn't allow omitting `d.ts` file extension. (There is a [discussion](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2267) here)
4. `import { TestType } from 'type'`. This means I omit all file extension and `import type` and just keep the filename itself. Again, I also have to install the eslint-import-resolver-typescript to prevent omitting file extension from throwing an error. The last way may be bad since it's hard to figure out what we import is a type or a value.